# Distinct Values in DropDownList's from one SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, drop-down-menu

I have ten DropDownList’s on one page. When I use the same datasource for all, there are duplicate values in all ten. Is there a way to use one SqlDataSource for all ten DropDownList’s and get only distinct values for each.

This is an example Dropdown and SqlDataSource:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="County" DataValueField="County"AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT Distinct * FROM [Personal]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does each dropdownlist have a different DataTextField and DataValueField defined?

Comment: yes each dropDownList will have a different DataTextField and DataValueField, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your sql query is returning dupes because you are using select *.  If you have any records in the table that have a field that is different from the others, such as an autoincrement primary key, you'll return those as well.  Distinct makes sure that the ENTIRE recordset is unique.

Try limiting your query to only the fields that you need.

```
SELECT Distinct County FROM [Personal]
```

Check this link:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: In that case I would need a different SqlDataSource for every DropDownList. Thanks Though.